# What is the use of chomp?

Tags: ruby

In this code snippet:

```
puts "You enter a dark room with two doors.  Do you go through door #1 or door #2?"

print "> "
door = $stdin.gets.chomp
```

what is the `chomp` call on the return value of `gets` for?

Comment: use google for questions like this. "ruby chomp" will lead you directly to documentation

Answer (score 3):

Just like the use of `chomp` in every other situation. If you get string from `gets`, it comes with trailing new line character. `chomp` removes it.

Answer (score 0):

In your above example

`gets` basically gets user input from stdin and returns a string which is passed to `chomp`

`chomp` returns a new String with the given record separator removed from the end of str (if present).

Comment: This string isn't passed to chomp, but chomp is called upon this string.